# Looping through excel file in folder skipping the pre-processed ones (vba)

Tags: vba, xls

I'm new to the site and I'm learning VBA.

Basically, I created a code which loops through excel files in a folder and processes some data which are subsequently implemented in a single common excel file with the name of the processed file in column A and all the data I want to record in the following cells.

Since I'm working with a lot of XSL files and the folder is constantly updated with new files, I was wondering which is the easiest way to go through the files once again when the macro starts and skipping the pre-processed files, in order to just record the new ones.

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

Add a function that checks if your file is already processed. Assuming that you have the list of processed files in column A of 1st Worksheet:

```
Function FileAlreadyProcessed(filename As String) As Boolean
    Dim r As Range, matchRes As Variant
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")

    matchRes = Application.Match(filename, r, 0)
    FileAlreadyProcessed = (Not IsError(matchRes))
End Function
```

This function will search Col A for the filename. When found, the function will return true, else false. So add a check in your loop

```
if not FileAlreadyProcessed(fileName) then
    ... do your processing
endif
```